# signal handler must be signal.SIG_IGN, signal.SIG_DFL, or a callable object

Tags: python, pyshark

I am trying to write some code to perform some packet sniffing with python
using pyshark.I have the following piece of code:

```
import pyshark
print('Pyshark demo')
capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='enp0s8')
```

However when I try to run this script I get the following stack trace:

```
Pyshark demo
Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseEventLoop.__del__ of <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=True debug=False>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 431, in __del__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 58, in close
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 139, in remove_signal_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/signal.py", line 47, in signal
TypeError: signal handler must be signal.SIG_IGN, signal.SIG_DFL, or a callable object
```

I have install pyshark.Do you have any idea what is causing this problem?

I run this on an ubuntu server 16.04

Comment: Same for me when using catkin-tools in deprecated trollius package (catkin still has dependency to trollius); Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

It is related to python issues:
https://bugs.python.org/issue26133

https://bugs.python.org/issue23548

https://bugs.python.org/issue28628?@ok_message=file%2045378%20created%0Amsg%20280182%20created%0Aissue%2028628%20created&@template=item

also see:
[Trigger catkin build process from within python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59612739/trigger-catkin-build-process-from-within-python)